# WebSocket communication in out-of-process BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp, windows-10

Is there any way to have a WebSocket run persistently in the background for a UWP application? So far I've tried `SocketActivityTrigger` and `ControlChannelTrigger`.

`SocketActivityTrigger` works nicely in the background even when the app has exited, but does not scale that well since you can only use a `StreamSocket` or `DatagramSocket`.

I've updated the existing Windows 8.1 example of `ControlChannelTrigger` with `StreamWebSocket` to a run on UWP, but I really don't get how this is supposed to be an example of a background task. All the websocket handling is done in foreground code and the background only dequeues and pops Toast notifications, once the foreground app is exited all websocket communication is killed.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Are there other options available?

Comment: What's the sample you are using? Do you mean [this one](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8)?

Comment: Yes, that's the sample I tried out.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?